# Why are electrons inherently magnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, magnetic-moment, dipole, point-particles

I read that permanent magnetism is caused by electrons orbiting in a way which produces a net magnetic field. but how can a particle with no dimensions have a magnetic dipole? also I read that photons are the fundamental carriers of electromagnetism. where does that come in here?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52843/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/418342/2451 and links therein.